# How to reuse pfsockopen resource

Tags: php, sockets

I'm looking for a solution to open 1 time a connection with the server, and reuse it many time, is that possible with pfsockopen() ?
And how can I reuse the resource ?

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself, or even read up on the PHP documentation? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php

Comment: i don't find any information that helpe me on the php documentation